# expectation equals 0 and probability.

Tags: probability, expectation

If the expectation of a continuous random variable $X$ is $0$, then can we prove that 
$$ P(X>0)=\dfrac{1}{2}\,\,\,?$$ 
If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

If the probability density function $f_X(x)$ is symmetric, i.e. $f_X(-x) = f_X(x)$, then clearly $\mathbb{E}\left(X\right) = 0$, provided $X$ is integrable. For such a density $$\Pr(X>0) = \Pr\left(X \leqslant 0\right) = \frac{1}{2}$$

However, the converse *is not* true, i.e. $\mathbb{E}\left(X\right)=0$ does not imply $f_X(-x) = f_X(x)$ and hence $\Pr(X>0) = \frac{1}{2}$ does not follow.

As a counter example consider a [triangular distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution) with $a=c=-1$ and $b=2$:
$$
    f_X(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{2}{9} \left(2-x\right) & -1 < x < 2 \cr 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$

[image]

Comment: Worth noting that the expected value is analogous to the mean and $p\ge0.5$ is analogous to the median - in *most* distributions they are not equal.